# Kendo UI Tooltip issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo UI MVC Asp.net tooltip control to show formatted data. But instead of showing the data along with the formatting, tooltip is showing HTML code.

[image: tootip image]

Using the below code segment to show the tooltip

TollTip('#calendar table tbody', "#timeTemplate", 'td a.aCurrent', "top");

```
function TollTip(target, template, filter, position) {
$(target).kendoTooltip({
    filter: filter,
    content: kendo.template($(template).html()),
    position: position
});
```

}

On the view I'm using following script snippet.

```
<script id="timeTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
            #if (target.data('title') != null) {#
            <p>
            #:target.data('title')#
            </p>
            #}#
</script>
```

What I am missing in the code?

Comment: What have you tried? What did you expect should happen? What did, or did not happen? Besides that, `TollTip` vs `ToolTip` perhaps? Also doesn't `kendo.Template` return a `kendo.Template` object and not an HTML string.

Comment: tooltip is showing me html code instead of formatted text

Answer (score 1):

```
function TollTip(target, template, filter, position) {
    $(target).kendoTooltip({
        filter: filter,
        content: function(e) { kendo.template($(template).html())(e) } ,
        position: position
    });
}
```

Comment: what i have to edit in your code snippet? It is showing me blank tooltip.